# Isomorphism of DVR quotient with quotient of completion

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm confused about the proof of Lemma 7.25 from J.S. Milne's course notes on algebraic number theory, available [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf).

Here is the situation: $A$ is the valuation ring corresponding to some discrete nonarchimedian valuation on a field, $\mathfrak m = (\pi)$ is the maximal ideal of $A$, and $\hat A$ is the completion of $A$ with respect the valuation mentioned.
The statement and proof of the lemma is as follows:

**Lemma 7.25** For every $n \in \mathbb N$, the map $A/\mathfrak m^n \to \hat A/ \hat {\mathfrak m}^n$ is an isomorphism.

*Proof.* Note that
$$
\mathfrak m^n = \{ a \in A \mid |a| \leq |\pi|^n \} = \{ a \in A \mid |a| < |\pi|^{n-1 }\}
$$
is both open and closed in $A$. Because it is closed, the map is injective; because $\hat{\mathfrak m}^n$ is open, the map is surjective.

I don't understand the last sentence.  If someone could explain it, I would be very grateful.

I believe that the map is surjective, since it is induced by the map $A \to \hat A \to \hat A/\hat{\mathfrak m}^n$, which has kernel $\mathfrak m^n$, but I'm not sure what this has to do with $\mathfrak m^n$ being closed.

Comment: This is Lemma $7.25$ in your link, not Lemma $7.5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure of $\mathfrak{m}$ in $\hat{A}$ is $\hat{\mathfrak{m}}$. This implies that the closure of $\mathfrak{m}$ in $A$, which, on the one hand, is clearly $\mathfrak{m}$ (because $\mathfrak{m}$ is closed in $A$) is, one the other hand, equal to $A\cap\hat{\mathfrak{m}}$. This equality is equivalent to the injectivity of the map in question.

Let $x\in\hat{A}$. Since $\hat{\mathfrak{m}}$ is open, $x+\hat{\mathfrak{m}}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $\hat{A}$. Since $A$ has dense image in $\hat{A}$, there is some $a\in A$ such that the image of $a$ in $\hat{A}$ lies in $x+\hat{\mathfrak{m}}$. This means that $a+\mathfrak{m}$ maps to $x+\hat{\mathfrak{m}}$ under the map in question, so you get surjectivity.